# Predicate not working when I try to pass string

Tags: ios, objective-c

its working:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dateSave ==[c] %@",[[UtilityClass   dateComponentsFromDate:[NSDate date]] valueForKey:@"date"]];
```

But I need to fetch:

```
str_predicate=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ AND hourSave == %d",str_predicate, [[[[self.dict_ChallengesAccepted  valueForKey:@"ChallengesAccepted"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"accept_time"]  intValue]+diff_Hour];

str_predicate=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ dateSave == %@",[str_predicate  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"1 AND "
                                                                                                            withString:@""],[[UtilityClass dateComponentsFromDate:[NSDate date]] valueForKey:@"date"]];
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:str_predicate]
```

Predicate Log= dateSave ==[c] "2014-09-26" AND hourSave ==[c] "18" AND hourSave hourSave ==[c] "19"

If I only pass dateSave ==[c] "2014-09-26" then its return data

but when I try to pass dateSave ==[c] "2014-09-26" AND hourSave ==[c] "18" AND hourSave hourSave ==[c] "19" return 0

but in my database there is data for 18 & 19 hour slot

**I am able to solve it:**

*My updated code is:*

```
int hourDiff=[[[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[UtilityClass dateComponentsFromDate: [NSDate date]]]valueForKey:@"hour"] intValue]-[[[[self.dict_ChallengesAccepted  valueForKey:@"ChallengesAccepted"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"accept_time"]intValue];
 for (int diff_Hour=0; diff_Hour<=hourDiff; diff_Hour++) {

            [predicatesArray addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"hourSave ==[c] %d", [[[[self.dict_ChallengesAccepted  valueForKey:@"ChallengesAccepted"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"accept_time"]   intValue]+diff_Hour]];
}
predicate=[NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicatesArray];

         NSArray *searchPredicatesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSPredicate  predicateWithFormat:@"dateSave ==[c] %@",[[[self.dict_ChallengesAccepted  valueForKey:@"ChallengesAccepted"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"accept_date"]],predicate,     nil];
predicate=[NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:searchPredicatesArray];
```

Comment: I am able to successfully solve my problem.  Below is my updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if something is equal to 18 then it can't be equal to 19, so you're providing wrong expression. You should use "OR" and parenthesis. Your final expression should look like this:

```
dateSave ==[c] "2014-09-26" AND (hourSave ==[c] "18" OR hourSave ==[c] "19")
```